# How to use python to find the maximum value in a csv file list

Tags: python

I am very new to python and need some help finding the maximum/highest value of in a column of data (time) that is imported from a csv file. this is the code i have tried.

```
file = open ("results.csv")
unneeded = file.readline()

for line in file:
    data = file.readline ()
    linelist = line.split(",")
    hours = linelist[4]
    maxtime = 0
    for x in hours:
        if x > maxtime:
            maxtime = x
print (maxtime)
```

any help is appreciated

edit: i tried this code but it gives me the wrong answer :(

```
file = open ("results.csv")
unneeded = file.readline()

maxtime = 0

for line in file:
    data = file.readline ()
    linelist = line.split(",")
    hours = linelist[4]
    if hours > str(maxtime):
        maxtime = hours
print (maxtime)
```

[first few lines of results][1]

edit:
results cvs
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3pEJ.png

Comment: put maxtime out of the for loop and check type of hours variable. Is it list or str. If it is str then remove line for x in hours:

Comment: Please post the first few lines of `results.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but this should work. Using the CSV library is easy for parsing CSV files.

```
import csv

with open("results.csv") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        hours = row[4]
        maxtime = 0
        if hours > maxtime:
            maxtime = x
print (maxtime)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is using the `pandas` module for anything CSV-related.

Using `dateutil`, I create a dataset of dates and identification numbers whose date values are shuffled (no specific order) like so:

```
from dateutil.parser import *
from dateutil.rrule import *
from random import shuffle

dates = list(rrule(
    DAILY,
    dtstart=parse("19970902T090000"),
    until=parse("19971224T000000")
))
shuffle(dates)

with open('out.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    for i,date in enumerate(dates):
        out.write(f'{i},{date}\n')
```

So thus, in this particular dataset, `1997-12-23 09:00:00` would be the "largest" date. Then, to extract the maximum date, we can just do it via string comparisons if it is formatted in the ISO 8601 date/time format:

```
from pandas import read_csv

df = read_csv('out.csv', names=['index', 'time'], header=1)
print(max(df['time']))
```

After running it, we indeed get `1997-12-23 09:00:00` printed in the terminal!